# Can we separate every options in select HTML control by line?

Tags: html, css

Can we separate every options in select HTML control by line?

I have below code

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

I need to add bottom-border in every options is it possible without js....???

Comment: have you tried adding it.?

Comment: is that so tough? http://jsfiddle.net/JvGSA/

Comment: @Mr.Alien that doesn't work in all browsers

Comment: @Mr.Alien what a coinsidance i wrote same jsfiddle with just having color different..i used `red`.

Comment: @DipeshParmar hehe :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how to do that via css, because it's usage is very limited for `option` tag, but one thing may help, but not perfect solution.
To add one disabled option with class `dis`.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option class='dis' disabled="disabled">--------</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option class='dis' disabled="disabled">--------</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option class='dis' disabled="disabled">--------</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option class='dis' disabled="disabled">--------</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option class='dis' disabled="disabled">--------</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

And css:

```
select option.dis {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JvGSA/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
   <option class="opt">1</option>
   <option class="opt">2</option>
   <option class="opt">3</option>
   <option class="opt">4</option>
   <option class="opt">5</option>
   <option class="opt">6</option>
</select>
```

css

```
.opt{   
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Try this

NB: This is not working for chrome. html `select` has many limitations for styling. However we can use some trucks to add styling the select box. For that

ref :http://cssglobe.com/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements/

Comment: @Kinjan Its not working for chrome. I made some changes on my answer see that

Comment: I can't use js for that.

Comment: I dont know how to do it without js. html select has many styling limitations so it not run on crome. To overcome that js is used.

Answer (score 0):

Browser support for `option` styling is very limited, if you want to style dropdowns I'd suggest looking into other means such as a tutorial found here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

This uses lists and jquery to create a dropdown that is fully customizable.

**Update:**

Or... look into:

- [SelectizeJS](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)
- [ChosenJS](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Try the below code:

```
<select>
    <option class="opt">1</option>
    <option class="opt">2</option>
    <option class="opt">3</option>
    <option class="opt">4</option>
    <option class="opt">5</option>
    <option class="opt">6</option>
</select>
```

and `CSS`

```
.opt
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

With CSS you can:

```
select option {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/jXmxm/

Comment: OOP's, 42? You stole that :D

Comment: @Mr. Alien No. I don't have account in Jsfiddle. so i updated the some one's link the previos was: http://jsfiddle.net/DfHSS/

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Ohk..!! I created my fiddle and updated the answer. Next time will not update other's.